# JNLP. Cause client to use JDK < 7 version

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

After some JDK 7 updates my applet won't work (security exceptions). How I can specify JRE version range to use by client in JNLP file? I want cause him to use only JRE 6, not 7.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a **Really Bad Idea**.

Java 6 has been EOL'ed and that means no more free security updates.  So what you are doing is encouraging people to **downgrade** the version of Java used by their web browsers to an **out of date** version of Java that is likely to have **unpatched security bugs** that could soon be being actively exploited to do all sorts of nasty things to the user.

The correct approach is to fix your applet so that it works with the latest JDK update (as well as older ones).

Comment: Further notes:  Fortunately Oracle (or perhaps it even stretched back to Sun) now explicitly *warns* the user if a JNLP requests an earlier version of Java.  With the way that Oracle is proceeding lately with tightening security, it will reach a stage when *most users* will be using a JRE with security levels that *prevent loading* such an app.  This is a good thing for both us and the users.  The users can have more confidence in installing the plug-in, and that means we the developers will need to jump through fewer hoops in order to ensure the user has the plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

The only way out is ,detect the version of java using in `browser` and giving him a proper message that ,use java 6 `jre`.

You might heard about [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html)

and check the version like

```
if(deployJava.versionCheck("1.7")){

//message him
}
```